# Startup script with LightDM, ~/.xprofile is not loaded

Tags: debian

Archwiki (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xprofile) I should use .xprofile for loading software and execute scripts at startup.

I am not using archlinux (I use debian, jessie) ~/.xprofile is ignored, I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How Debian handles the Xsession startup is summarized e.g. [here](https://wiki.debian.org/Xsession).

I would first try to put what you have in your `~/.xprofile` into an `~/.xsessionrc` (you might have to create it). This should not interfere with however the rest of your startup is working.

However, from the same page:

> Also note that because ~/.xsessionrc is read very early, any settings you place here may be overridden by your window manager or desktop environment, later in the login sequence.

Comment: I will try that out